# Xcode 15: After deploy build to TestFlight, fonts have another style

Tags: ios, fonts, swift5, testflight, xcode15

We did update macos and Xcode to the latest releases (macos Sonoma, and Xcode 15). After deploying our app to TestFlight we see strange issue that all custom fonts in application was changed from Regular style to Medium/Bold style.

When we run app on Device or on Simulator, sometimes fonts styles also was broken.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did update to Xcode 15.0.1 RC solved problem